# Minified JS on live site display weird characters causing JS to crash?

Tags: javascript

I have uploaded a minified JS file which i'm using locally and on a test server without any issues. However when i upload the site to an live environment and open op the console log i get undefined JS.

but when i look at the minified file i see this weird characters:

```
H=Math.max(e.innerWidth||0,A.clientWidth)!==W.width||A.clientHeight!=@F›����@F›��������������������pË‡������������0ÎŒ����¨F›������������`F›�����@������`F›������������,y.fillImgs=te,y.teardownRun=
```

All over the place?

How is this possible?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Check the text encoding in your text editor. Convert to UTF8 if possible and try again

Comment: Thanks you for the help!

Comment: Did this solve your problem? It it good now?

Comment: How are you uploading the file to the live environment?

Comment: @JeremyThille Nginx server setting incorrect charset on upload. Thanks guys!